# X64 and x32 FreeBSD, memory alocation intro application

Tags: c++, memory, x86-64, freebsd, i386

i have compiled a program intro a FreeBSD 10.2 X32bit.
And i want to move that precompiled binary intro amd64 and run it.

Why ? I need much ram memory, i think i need more than 64gb ram memory.

My question it's : 
1) If i compile a application intro i386 machine , how much memory can handle(I want that app to can use all 64gb memory ram) that application intro amd64 ? All memory ?

2) It's possible to compile my program intro i386 and instruct the compiler to allow more than 4gb for my application ?

The ideea is i want my application to have acces to all resources, because i have a server with many conexions and i use bufers to store data intro ram memory.  And i need muchhhhh ram.

Thanks. :d I hope you guys understand what i mean.

Comment: If you create a 32-bit application, it has 32 bits of address-space, even if you run it on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Just compile for 64bit.  x86-32 is obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of memory your application can address depends on the architecture you build it **for**. If you want your application to be able to access more than 4 GiB of memory, you must compile it for a 64-bit architecture. Obviously, you need to run it on a 64-bit OS too.

If you really need to build it **on** a 32-bit host, then it's still possible to produce a 64-bit program, by [using cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).